# DateRangePicker onChange need to call action in stimulus js

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker, stimulusjs

Iam using daterange picker plugin with stimulus js. Everything works fine, the issue is I have to call change function whenever I change the date in the date picker, but I can't able to call the action function (this.action) in stimulus js. Since stimulus js function can't able to access inside the onchange of the date picker.

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left',
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
              },
        maxDate:parseInt(moment().subtract(30, 'days'), moment()),
        locale: {
          format: 'MMM DD, YYYY '
        },
      }).on('apply.daterangepicker', function(e, picker) {
        this.startDate= moment($("input[name='daterange']").data('daterangepicker').startDate._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        this.endDate=moment($("input[name='daterange']").data('daterangepicker').endDate._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        this.onDateChange()//throws error

      });
onDateChange(){
alert("date")
}
```

Comment: I think you should check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124456/onchange-event-of-daterangepicker-js-predefined-date-range) which has similar solution.
and add `autoApply: true, //Remove Apply button in calendar`

Comment: why use `this` on `onDateChnage()`? `onDateChange()` is not a function in the daterangepicker

Comment: @ChandJogani I tried that too. thats not working, the same issue cause

Comment: @BennyYen all the functions are bound to this in s stimulus js.

Comment: But in that scope, I think `this` is daterangpicker `<input>`